# CSS counters - Demo works, fails in the browser

Tags: css, css-counter

While trying to implement *Hugo Giraudel*'s awesome CSS counters [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/accessible-footnotes-css/), things fail when I try to set it up in the browser.

I'm not using `counter-reset` or `increment`, so I'm not sure which references need to be changed. In my example, I only have two references that need to be counted - the links appear to be correct, but the counter does not change from 1 to 2.

Short example below...

```
Low level <a href="#features" aria-describedby="footnote-label" id="features-ref">features</a> don't come into existence in the span of a year.

<a href="#criticism" aria-describedby="footnote-label" id="criticism-ref">criticism</a> they receive for this stance.

<footer>
  <h2 class="visually-hidden" id="footnote-label">Footnotes</h2>
  <ol>
    <li id="features">
      Swift took 4 years. LLVM reached the 1.0 milestone in 2003. <a href="#features-ref" aria-label="Back to content">↩</a>
    </li>
    <li id="criticism">
      In Apple's case, it might be, "Damn the investors and pundits!" <a href="#criticism-ref" aria-label="Back to content">↩</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</footer>
```

Comment: *I'm not using counter-reset or increment* - but then how would the counter get initialized or incremented?

Comment: Ugh. The styles in Hugo's example should apply here, my mistake. Haven't checked in an inspector to make sure if it is being loaded